# How to add the lostfocus event handler to a dynamically created combobox's textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

The Combobox is NOT editable But I have tried:

```
TextBox TxtBox = (TextBox)myCombo.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", myCombo);
```

But it turns null.

I have tried adding it to the Windows xaml:

```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Border x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" Focusable="True" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

but get System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred:

```
Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.DeferrableContent' threw an exception.
```

Here is the code that I use to create the Combobox and set it's position in a Grid:

```
public static System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox createNewComboBox(String newComboBoxName, SelectionChangedEventHandler selectionChangedEventHandler,RoutedEventHandler lostFocusEventHandler)
    {
        System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox newComboBox = new System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox();
        newComboBox.Name = newComboBoxName;
        if (selectionChangedEventHandler != null) newComboBox.SelectionChanged += selectionChangedEventHandler;
        if (lostFocusEventHandler != null) newComboBox.LostFocus += lostFocusEventHandler;
        return newComboBox;
    }

    public static void setNewControlLocation(System.Windows.Controls.Control control, Int32 rowIndex, Int32 columnIndex, Grid parent)
    {
        Grid.SetRow(control, rowIndex);
        Grid.SetColumn(control, columnIndex);
        parent.Children.Add(control);
    }
```

This will add the lostfocus to the combobox not the combobox's text box.

There is one row where the user selects and enters data. The user can add more rows by clicking the plus button or the left hand side of the screen or using the F5 key. The row contains several controls one of which is a combobox. The comboboxes drops down a list of product names requires a messagebox to display if certain products are selected. If I put the code in the SelectionChanged event handler and the user is searching the combobox the messagebox will show everytime they pass one of the products that requires it. If I put the code for the messagebox in the combobox's lostfocus event handler it fires when you click on the combobox's textbox and when I close the window. So I need to find a way to attach the event handler to the combobox's textbox.

If there is another way of going about this let please let me know.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Why are you creating UI elements in code to begin with? that's what XAML is for, you know...

Comment: `CreateNewComboBox`, `SetNewControlLocation`... your code looks so much winforms that it makes me feel like vomiting all the way back home

Comment: HighCore - The UI elements are being created in code because the number of the UI elements is designated by the use. There could be one or there could be 50. There is also no need to be rude, I'm learning. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Then you need to use an `ItemsControl` (or one of it's derivatives (such as `ListBox`) depending on your needs, and define a proper `DataTemplate` for every item you need to show.

Comment: Post a Screenshot of what you need and I can tell you the proper way to do it in WPF. You must forget the winforms mentality and embrace MVVM. Otherwise you will fail miserably in WPF, as not using the right patterns leads to the kind of horrible hacks you're having to deal with here (such as `.Template.FindName()`)